# Calling g@ from a a vimscript function

Tags: vimscript

I want to call `g@` from a function.

Given an operation:

```
" Taken from :help g@
function! CountSpaces(type, ...)
  let sel_save = &selection
  let &selection = "inclusive"
  let reg_save = @@

  if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use gv command.
    silent exe "normal! gvy"
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']y"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]y"
  endif

  echomsg strlen(substitute(@@, '[^ ]', '', 'g'))

  let &selection = sel_save
  let @@ = reg_save
endfunction
```

I want to call it from:

```
function! my_fun(...)
        set opfunc=CountSpaces
        normal! g@
endfunction
```

But it doesn't work, nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Normally, this is done from a mapping, though I don’t see why it shouldnt work. Do note that `my_fun` probably needs an uppercase start

Comment: `g@` needs a motion. Therefore `normal! g@` does nothing. (But, for example, `normal! g@$` will work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `g@` must be used with a motion, so it effectively switches to the operator-pending mode. However, that will not work in your example.

From `:h :normal`:

```
{commands} should be a complete command.  If
{commands} does not finish a command, the last one
will be aborted as if <Esc> or <C-C> was typed.
```

So eventually `normal! g@` ends the operator-pending mode and falls back into the normal mode. Hence `g@` does just nothing.

Simply supplying any motion will work (e.g. `normal! g@$`), but it's almost useless, as normally we want an operator, not a fixed operation. That's the reason `g@` should be invoked by a mapping, like in `:h g@`.